# Do EU residents who are citizen of a non-EU country need a transit visa in London?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, turkish-citizens

I will travel to US for a conference at the end of the April, and I might be using British Airways which has a connecting flight in London.

I am working in Spain and have a residence permit (since October). I wonder even if I have this card would I need to apply for a transit visa? I am a citizen of Turkey. I wonder if also Brexit has any consequences on this?

Comment: Brexit wont happen until 2019 at the earliest.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez Article 50 of the Lisbon Treaty does permit withdrawal to happen less than two years after notification, so it *could* - but I would agree that that is unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on the [GOV.UK website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/turkey/transit/somewhere_else/no), being a resident of Spain, as well as a US visa holder, you do **not** need a transit visa. Just be sure to present your US visa at the bag drop and the gate, which you have to anyway.

To clarify, you can transit the UK without a visa either with a US visa or Spanish residence permit. You have both!

If you have two separate bookings, you'll need to cross the UK border to pick up and re-check the luggage. In this case, present your passport (open at the page with the US visa), residence permit, e-ticket of the connecting flight and filled-out landing card (which airline crew will distribute - but **only** take one if you're going to enter the UK)

If an ignorant bag drop or gate agent tries to deny you boarding without a visa, insist that they check Timatic, a database which has all info about these things. In that case, make sure to tell the agent to put in "Alien resident of"=Spain, and the UK as the transit, NOT destination, country.

As for Brexit, literally no one knows - they haven't even started the negotations yet.

Comment: You refer to this item, is that right: `a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland`? I will have single flight purchased from British Airways (Madrid->Londong->US), and there is only 2-hour wait in London. Then, I believe I can go ahead and book my ticket without worrying about the visa!

Comment: and also thanks for this caution `If an ignorant bag drop or gate agent tries to deny you boarding without a visa, insist that they check Timatic, a database which has all info about these things.`

Comment: @renakre See my latest update!

Comment: Yes! (`either with a US visa`)

Comment: @renakre "a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used for travel to any country)"